# Why does next() always display the same value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, yield

I was practicing the `yield` statement. I have written the following function in Python 2.7:

```
>>> def mygen():
...     i = 0
...     j = 3
...     for k in range(i, j):
...         yield k
...
>>> mygen().next()
0
>>> mygen().next()
0
>>> mygen().next()
0
```

Whenever I call the `mygen().next()` it always displays output as `0`, instead of `0`, `1`, `2` & `StopIteration`. Can anybody please explain this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are *recreating* the generator each time, so it starts from the beginning each time.

Create the generator **once**:

```
gen = mygen()
gen.next()
gen.next()
gen.next()
```

Generator functions produce a new iterator every time you call them; that way you can produce multiple independent copies. Each independent iterator is an invocation of the function that can be stepped through separately from the others:

```
>>> def mygen():
...     i = 0
...     j = 3
...     for k in range(i, j):
...         yield k
...
>>> gen1 = mygen()
>>> gen2 = mygen()
>>> gen1.next()
0
>>> gen1.next()
1
>>> gen2.next()
0
>>> gen2.next()
1
>>> gen1.next()
2
>>> gen1.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Note that you probably want to use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) instead of calling `generator.next()` directly:

```
next(gen)
```

`generator.next()` is considered a hook (Python 3 renamed it to `generator.__next__()` and the `next()` function is the official API to invoke it in a cross-version compatible way.

Answer (score 0):

A function definition containing a yield statement returns a generator. You have to apply the next function to that generator in stead of the function itself. To clarify, your function definition is equivalent to:

```
    def mygen():
        i, j = 0, 3
        return (k for k in range(i, j))
```

or:

```
    mygen = lambda :(k for k in range(0, 3))
```

So you would use it like this:

```
    gen1 = mygen()
    gen2 = mygen()
    next(gen1) // returns 0
    next(gen1) // returns 1
    list(gen1) // returns [2]
    list(gen2) // returns [0, 1, 2]
```